# Why shouldn't question 8102 be closed?

Tags: discussion

Skimming (tl;dr) over the question [I want to convert, but I have family issue](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/8102/3487) I found - not being apathetic - has no reason to remain open. All it is asking for is *advice*. The entire question has a single *"?"*, that too in front of question which is off-topic on this site. Leaving it open would set a bad example for existing, new and future users.

So, why shouldn't it be closed?

Comment: what is problem of advice when advice is based on Islam? an answer can be an Islamic advice.

Comment: One problem. This is not an *Islamic* forum. [Islam SE: Not a Muslim Peer Support Group](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/189/3487)

Comment: asking for Islamic advice in form of QA does not make site to an Islamic forum. but only if the answer is based on Islam laws. asking for Islamic advice is a kind of question.

Comment: You could defend and provide your view in a cogent answer.